# Filter Array of Object

Tags: reactjs

I have Array of Object and each object have different properties inside it. What I am trying to do is filter the object in that array by its different properties but my problem is the name of the properties and number of properties are changing. How can I filter it by not declaring hard code values on it.

I have used the following code before but the number of filtering is static

```
events={MainObject.filter(
    itemX =>

       FilteringParameter["DropdownFilter2"].find(
        parameter => parameter === itemX["DropdownFilter2"]
       ) &&
       (FilteringParameter["DropdownFilter1"].find(
       parameter => parameter === itemX["DropdownFilter1"]
       ) ||
       !FilteringParameter["DropdownFilter1"].length)
)}
```

On my code above the "DropdownFilter1" and "DropdownFilter2" is based on a multi select dropdown and has a value based on the distinct values from my Objects

Comment: Well how are you intending to filter it if you don't even know what values to filter it by?

Comment: The Object that I get in the array will be used to create a table. And the unique values for each column is fed to different dropdownlist

Comment: each column has its own column.

Comment: I want to used that dropdownlist a filtering feature to filter my array of object before I fed it to my component table

Comment: I have done this before but the number of dropdown list are static ("Hard coded")

Comment: So not sure if its possible to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Wow I figure it out how to make it dynamic filter. I am not sure if this is the best answer but I made a loop that will filter my data each loop

```
let z = RawData
   filterObject.map(e => {
       z = z.filter(d => {
         return d[e.Title] === e.Value
       })
    })
```

My filterObject holds all my dropdown value which has two properties. Title is the property name while Value holds the value of the dropdown.